# Jenkins declarative pipeline: post script conditions

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a declarative Jenkins pipeline.
I want to have a conditional in the "post" section of a build.

Is it possible to have "script blocks" in the post section of a jenkins file?

When I put it like this, no errors occur, but no hipchat messages are sent. Even if say "if master branch, hipchatSend, else hipchatSend", no hipchat messages are sent.  Heck, if I replace hipchatSend with "echo" statements, nothing happens either.

```
post {
  always {
    script {
      if (env.BRANCH_NAME == "master") {
        hipchatSend color: 'RED', credentialId: 'HipChat-Jenkins-Token',
                    message: 'I am master branch',
                    room: 'Master-Commit-Room,',
                    sendAs: '', 
                    server: '',
                    v2enabled: true
      }
      if (env.BRANCH_NAME == "release/my-release") {
        hipchatSend color: 'RED', credentialId: 'HipChat-Jenkins-Token',
                    message: 'I am release branch',
                    room: 'Release-Commit-Room,',
                    sendAs: '',
                    server: '',
                    v2enabled: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I have set up Jenkins declarative pipelines which successfully uses script blocks in the post section the way you describe.

Example:

```
post {
    always {
        script {
            // arbitrary script code runs successfully here
        }
    }
}
```

... and it works as expected. Have you verified that your if conditions evaluate as expected?

Note: I'm using the "Pipeline: Declarative" plugin (id  pipeline-model-definition) version 1.3.2 on Jenkins 2.138.2).

Comment: I am getting "No such DSL method" exception when trying to call some my groovy functions from such "script" section. How to use arbitrary groovy code in such script section ?

Answer (score -2):

Use `when`

```
stage('Deploy') {
        when { branch 'master' }
        steps {
            sh './docker-commands.sh deploy || exit 1'
        }
    }
```

Here is more [examples](https://github.com/cvitter/jenkins-pipeline-examples/blob/master/Jenkinsfile-When) how to use `when`